# Не работает babel на gulp

Tags: gulp, babel

Что я делал, чтобы установить Бабель на gulp:

1. npm i babili --save-dev
2. "Зарекваил" пакет в gulpfile.js

И я не знаю, почему он не работает... Везде пишут такого рода код (ниже) + команду, которую я привел, и всё, по идее всё должно заработать.
Вот гаплфайл с таксом `js`:

```
var  
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  babel = require('babili');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src([
                'assets/_js/*.js'
                ])
                .pipe(babel({presets: ['babili']}))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/js'))
});
```

А вот ошибка:

```
[01:08:34] Starting 'js'...
[01:08:34] 'js' errored after 2.72 ms
[01:08:34] TypeError: babel is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\gulpfile.js:77:11)
    at module.exports (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:279:18
    at finish (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at module.exports (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:60:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\gulp-sync\lib\index.js:51:27)
    at module.exports (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\Vostok Sisters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
hard doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам, вероятно, нужен пакет [gulp-babili](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babili)

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const babili = require("gulp-babili");

gulp.task("js", () =>
  gulp.src(['assets/_js/*.js'])
    .pipe(babili({
      mangle: {
        keepClassNames: true
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/js'));
);
```

Comment: Да, уже разрбрался, его и установил, спасибо.